# Regular expression: match zero characters?

Tags: php, regex

`/^.{0,10}$/`

I want to match any string 0-10 characters in length. The above will match a string with 1-10 characters but doesn't match a string with zero characters.

Comment: "string with zero characters" - it sound like nothing, so what should it match?

Comment: I guess it's better to use strlen, gave up regex. To my mind, Regex is too heavy for this case.

Comment: @JNF: Wrong, it produces a syntax error.

Comment: Where is your problem? Your expression `/^.{0,10}$/` already matches strings with 0 characters. Have you tested your expression?

Comment: Works pretty fine for me. How do you use it?

Comment: ok it works... I had an unrelated error in the code... sorry dumb question.

Comment: @Sunny: Right, so you could delete the question.

Comment: I already did, but it won't let me.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just check the length of the string?

```
if(strlen($string) <= 10) {
    ...
}
```

And maybe call `trim()` before that.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be doing the trick

```
^.{0,10}$
```

On this web site you can try,

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-aPpvbcrl9QbF0E6)

Comment: How is it different from OP's.